# Put sequential number into the number with condition with blackslash

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using office 365 excel.
According to my sheets, it contains lists of products sold for each invoice which means they are somewhat duplicates assumingly as follows:

invoice details sheets:
[image]

I would like the formula to
change 18414/1 to be 18415 instead while
shift 18415 to 18416 and onwards...

how can i do this? Please help! Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: To change it in same cell, you will need VBA coding. Otherwise results will be displayed in another column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this formula:

```
=LET(data,A2:A10,
diff,--(data<>INDEX(data,SEQUENCE(ROWS(data),,0))),
SCAN(INDEX(data,1),diff,LAMBDA(a,v,a+v)))
```

`diff` returns 1 per row whenever it is different from the previous row. This array is then added using `SCAN`.

Assumption: the first invoice id is a true number!

[image]

Comment: hello, thank you very much for your kindness, however, the excel said there's a problem with this formula, could you please shines light for me please?

Comment: Sorry, try again - I posted a "german" semicolon instead of comma. I updated the formula in the answer

Comment: Oh thank you so much! IT WORKS!!! DANKE SCHOEN!! :-D